# Is it possible to integrate picturebox and labels inside a Listview? as a User control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview, user-controls

I want to create a listview type user control which'll have a picturebox and a label inside each item. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not just use the imagelist attached to the default listview?

Comment: Ooops.. I wrote wrong. It'll be ListBox. not ListView.. :-\ Should I change the title or open a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking this control for a windows forms application, there is a control already implemented for your need. [Image List View.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/OAKListView.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

edit: My bad, I've missread your question.
The answer below is correct tho.

[ListView With Images](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/OAKListView.aspx)